# Can't change color with a css class

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry if this is too basic, css confuses me.

So I have this "button":

```
<div class="col-md-12 bloque izq boton-tarjetas" onclick="mostrarTarjetas()">
    <p class="titulo2">- Tarjetas de Invitacion</p>
</div>
```

That button uses this css class:

```
.boton-tarjetas {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #508365;
}
```

And when hovered over the button, the `backgound-color` property changes using this css class:

```
.boton-tarjetas:hover, .boton-activo {
    background-color: #30513d;
}
```

If the button es clicked, this js function triggers an accordion:

```
function mostrarTarjetas() {
    $('.contenido-tarjetas').slideToggle();
    $('.boton-tarjetas').toggleClass('boton-activo');
}
```

And that very same js function adds the `boton-activo` class to the button.

All that is working wonderfully, the problem is that the button should change color when hovered over (which is working) and when is clicked it should stay that color due to the added class on the js function.

If i check on the devtools, the `boton-activo` class is working, but it's being overwritten by the `background-color` property of the `boton-tarjetas` class.

Please help me.

Comment: show us the order of your CSS

Comment: could you try adding `!important` after a CSS rule?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight `!important` is almost always an avoidable hack, best not to recommend it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is due to selector precedence. You need to make the `.boton-activo` class more specific so that it overrides any previous styles:

```css
.boton-tarjetas {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #508365;
}

.boton-tarjetas:hover, 
.boton-tarjetas.boton-activo { /* note additional class selector here */
  background-color: #30513d;
}
```

Note that the `!important` flag is another possible solution, but that should be avoided unless there is absolutely no alternative.

Comment: using this order you don't need to add another class ... the last one will win since they have same specificity

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's true, but I find it's better to be explicit just in case someone rearranges your CSS files :)

Comment: Ok, but you may create confusion saying that the issue is precedence with that order ... I would probably explain it differently and say that it's better to add another class to be sure it will work whataver the order is.

Answer (score 0):

selector need to be more specific

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 button-target">
<p class="title">accordian Title</p>
<div class="content-target">
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the  majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-target {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #508365;
 } 
.button-target:hover, .button-target.button-active {
  background-color: #30513d;
 }
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('.button-target').click(function() {
   $('.content-target').slideToggle();
   $('.button-target').toggleClass('button-active');
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/Danielprabhakaran_N/xpvt214o/581603/